# How to measure the connector length in visio with python?

Tags: python, xml, visio, connector

I am trying to measure the length of each connector in a visio file which i use for planning power line length in a house floor plan.

I cannot find the start coordinates of the connector geometry in a Microsoft Visio file.

I use python to unzip the *.vsdx (Visio 2019) and analyse the page1.xml

But i cannot find the start of the geometry. I try to figure out the help of microsoft but it is not getting me anywhere.

A simple connector:

```xml
<Shape ID='1' NameU='Dynamic connector' Name='Dynamischer Verbinder' Type='Shape' Master='2'>
<Cell N='PinX' V='4.03543297686481' F='Inh'/>
<Cell N='PinY' V='6.397637646249088' F='Inh'/>
<Cell N='Width' V='0.1968503937007874' F='GUARD(0.19685039370079DL)'/>
<Cell N='Height' V='-3.740157393191775' F='GUARD(EndY-BeginY)'/>
<Cell N='LocPinX' V='0.09842519685039369' F='Inh'/>
<Cell N='LocPinY' V='-1.870078696595888' F='Inh'/>
<Cell N='BeginX' V='3.937007782307131'/>
<Cell N='BeginY' V='8.267716342844976'/>
<Cell N='EndX' V='4.133858171422488'/>
<Cell N='EndY' V='4.527558949653201'/>
<Cell N='LayerMember' V='0'/>
<Cell N='BegTrigger' V='1' F='_XFTRIGGER(Sheet.1!EventXFMod)'/>
<Cell N='EndTrigger' V='1' F='_XFTRIGGER(Sheet.1!EventXFMod)'/>
<Cell N='TxtPinX' V='2.292715350904473E-9' F='Inh'/>
<Cell N='TxtPinY' V='-1.968503891153566' F='Inh'/>
<Section N='Control'>
<Row N='TextPosition'>
<Cell N='X' V='2.292715350904473E-9'/>
<Cell N='Y' V='-1.968503891153566'/>
<Cell N='XDyn' V='2.292715350904473E-9' F='Inh'/>
<Cell N='YDyn' V='-1.968503891153566' F='Inh'/>
</Row>
</Section>
<Section N='Geometry' IX='0'>
<Row T='MoveTo' IX='1'>
<Cell N='X' V='2.292715350904473E-9'/>
</Row>
<Row T='LineTo' IX='2'>
<Cell N='X' V='2.292715350904473E-9'/>
<Cell N='Y' V='-3.740157393191775'/>
</Row>
<Row T='LineTo' IX='3'>
<Cell N='X' V='0.1968503914080722'/>
<Cell N='Y' V='-3.740157393191775'/>
</Row>
</Section>
</Shape>
```

I expect to find the start of the Geometry, but its not there?

I dont understand the "moveto" part?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have chosen a really hard way of doing things (calculating length, in particular). Usually for similar tasks, Visio itself is used, it provides a humane API to calculate connector length. What would you do for example if the connector is a bezier curve? Well, it can be, theoretically :)

[image]

With python on windows, you could try to use python COM module (`win32com` for example). Then connector length calculation is done by Visio and using it is kind of trivial:

[connector.LengthIU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.shape.lengthiu)

Regarding the "MoveTo" part - I believe trivial (zero) parts can be omitted in the vsdx, 
therefore there is no data for the Y cell, i.e. I'm talking about missing `<Cell N='Y' V='0'/>`. But I'm not 100% sure. Also please note that values in the geometry section are relative (to the shape pin).